# Load joblib/pickle files from Databricks file system

Tags: filesystems, load, pickle, azure-databricks, joblib

I have a problem: I can't see to load objects from dbfs (data bricks file system) outside of spark (I can load the data fine with spark but not with pandas).

The objects we want to load are joblib and pickled files.

```html
corps_encoder = "/dbfs:/mnt/xxxx/encoders/corpsEncoder.joblib"

corpsEncoding = joblib.load(f'/dbfs:/mnt/xxxx/encoders/corpsEncoder.joblib')
```

Here the error message:

```html
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs:/mnt/xxxx/encoders/corpsEncoder.joblib'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2364347171462503> in <module>
      1 #corps_encoder = "/dbfs:/mnt/xxxx/encoders/corpsEncoder.joblib"
----> 2 corpsEncoding = joblib.load(f'/dbfs:/mnt/xxxx/encoders/corpsEncoder.joblib')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    575             obj = _unpickle(fobj)
    576     else:
--> 577         with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    578             with _read_fileobject(f, filename, mmap_mode) as fobj:
    579                 if isinstance(fobj, str):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs:/mnt/xxxx/encoders/corpsEncoder.joblib'
```

Any idea of how to load this type of file on db?

Comment: Did you try with path like `/dbfs/mnt/<yourpath>`?

Comment: yes, it says file not found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. Your admin needs to set up a configuration for you to be able to load DBFS files.
This is the reference. Idk why but it's not turned on by default
https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/workspace/settings/dbfs-browser.html